# Link wordpress page to php file not working

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I got a wordpress page called "Galerie". I'd like to display some content on this page. So I createda php file called "content-galerie.php" and wrote some content in it.
But the content is not displaying at all. It only displays the default page with the header, the title and the footer.
How can i fix that? So my content gets displayed?
For example a simple Text

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing...</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create Page template for gallery section.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Gallery
*
* This is the template that displays all pages by default.
* Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that
* other "pages" on your WordPress site will use a different template.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
* @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
*/

get_header();

?>


 // You can write your gallery content here


<section class="section single-page">
<div class="fixed_container">
    <?php
    // Start the loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        // Include the page content template.
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
            comments_template();
        }

        // End of the loop.
    endwhile;
    ?>


</div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

After that edit you gallery page from admin and assign this template to your gallery page.

Comment: thank you so much :) its working! but the header is overlapping the footer and the content... should i just add some <br>'s or is there another solution?

Comment: These are the dummy classes(section single-page,fixed_container) which I have used.
You can replace this classes with yours.
open your "Page.php" and follow the same classes structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created "content-galerie.php" page in theme folder then you can that page like this.

```
get_template_part('content-galerie');
```

Comment: Where do i have to add this code? I added it right to my "content-galerie.php" and its still not showing any content

Comment: put this file in theme's folder and write this code in the file where you want to display the content.

Comment: The file is already in the theme folder. But i want to write some content in the content-galerie.php file and its not displaying anything on the webpage...[link](http://gartenlustig.ch/galerie/) like you see on that page

Comment: For that please follow my another answer.